# "Suggest" meaning "recommend"

Tags: grammar, verbs, ditransitivity

Page 456 of the Collins English Usage reads

> When you suggest something, you mention it as a plan or idea for
> someone to consider.
> You do not 'suggest someone something': you 'suggest something to
> someone'.
>
> Nor do you 'suggest someone to do something' unless *suggest* means
> '***recommend***': You 'suggest that someone does something.'
>
> *Beatrice suggested that he spend the summer at their place*

I do not understand what meaning other than *recommned* is being used for the distinction.

Secondly, with the meaning of "recommend", can you 'suggest someone something'?

Comment: They are concentrating on the correct pattern. You are concentrating on the meaning. People learning English often make the mistakes they point out.

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary entry is trying to explain a mistake often made by non-natives.

Those mistakes are these:

1. - suggest someone something [BUZZER}
2. - suggest someone to do something [BUZZER}

Suggest works like this:

- I suggest **you finish early**. [followed by a clause, with or without that].
  VERSUS
- What did you suggest? I **suggested cake,** not biscuits **be served** at the party. [followed by a passive clause, same thing re that]
- I suggested **he read the book** *to learn the rules of the game.*

Recommend works like this:

- I recommended you leave early. [clause]
- I recommended him (for the job). [indirect object,him]
- I recommended the job to him. [direct object, job]
- I suggested that, not this. [direct object]

No, you cannot "recommend someone something", just as the Collins says. But:

***You can *recommend something to someone***
***You can *suggest something to someone***.

As for the difference, a recommendation is more formal than a suggestion.

- I suggest you close that window. It's cold in here.

Closing a window would not usually be something you recommend in casual conversation.

However, you might say to a friend: I recommend you see a doctor for that knee.

BUT

- Experts have recommended we keep the windows open as late as possible in the season due to the Covid-19 pandemic.

recommendations are generally more formal things compared to suggestions.

[reference: me own head]